# How does this Linked list Sort solution work?

Tags: java, data-structures

Im working on some leetcode question and I dont understand this solution and cant find an answer there so I need some clarification please. The quesition is to sort a linked list. This solution uses a merge sort approach. The solution is below

```
class Solution {
public ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null)
        return head;
    ListNode mid = getMid(head);
    ListNode left = sortList(head);
    ListNode right = sortList(mid);
    return merge(left, right);
}

ListNode merge(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
    ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode();
    ListNode tail = dummyHead;
    while (list1 != null && list2 != null) {
        if (list1.val < list2.val) {
            tail.next = list1;
            list1 = list1.next;
            tail = tail.next;
        } else {
            tail.next = list2;
            list2 = list2.next;
            tail = tail.next;
        }
    }
    tail.next = (list1 != null) ? list1 : list2;
    return dummyHead.next;
}

ListNode getMid(ListNode head) {
    ListNode midPrev = null;
    while (head != null && head.next != null) {
        midPrev = (midPrev == null) ? head : midPrev.next;
        head = head.next.next;
    }
    ListNode mid = midPrev.next;
    midPrev.next = null;
    return mid;
}
```

}

So in the sortList method on the line

```
 ListNode left = sortList(head);
```

how does this assignment work? Head is not incremented so on each recursive call wouldnt it just call the method over and over again on the same value?

I've walked through this by hand and heres where i get stuck.

```
5 -> 3 -> 4
SortList(5)
head = 5 
mid = getMid(5) == 3
        getMid(5)
            mid prev = null    -> 5
            head = 5           -> 4
            mid = 3 
            return 3 
left = sortList(5)
      mid = getMid(5) = 3
      left = sortList(5)
            mid = sortList(5) = 3
            left = sortList(5)
```

As you can see theres always a call to sortList(5) for every assignment to left. I'm pretty decent and leetcode but this question is really stumping me. All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It works because `getMid(head)` splits the list into two sublists.

After the first call to `getMid()` you have the two sublists:

```
head: 5
mid:  3 -> 4
```

Calling `sortList(head)` on the first sublist returns immediately (because `head.next` is null)

Calling `sortList(mid)` with the second sublist splits that list into two further sublists:

```
head': 3
mid': 4
```

Calling `sortList` on both sublists also returns immediately (because in both sublists `head.next` is null).

The code then proceeds to merge `head'` and `mid'` which results in `3 -> 4`.

After that the list `head` and the result of the previous merge (`3 -> 4`) are merged together, which gives the final result:

```
3 -> 4 -> 5
```

---

I try to explain in a bit more detail with some pictures.

This is the list on the first call to `sortList(head)`:

```
        ListNode    ListNode    ListNode
head -> next     -> next     -> next     -> null
        val: 5      val: 3      val: 4
```

`getMid(head)` changes the list and returns a reference to the middle element:

```
        ListNode
head -> next     -> null
        val: 5

        ListNode    ListNode
mid  -> next     -> next     -> null
        val: 3      val: 4
```

That is, although the reference `head` itself did not change, the list it references changed because `head.next` changed!

What happens if we call `sortList(head)` with this reduced list?

The first statement in `sortList(head)` is

```
if (head == null || head.next == null)
    return head;
```

Calling `sortList(head)` (second level) with the reduced list

```
        ListNode
head -> next     -> null
        val: 5
```

has `head.next == null`, so it returns immediately the value of `head` and in the caller results in `left` being set to the value of `head`.

The next line in the first level of the `sortList()` call is `ListNode right = sortList(mid);`.

Calling `sortList(head)` (second level) with the split of list

```
        ListNode    ListNode
mid  -> next     -> next     -> null
        val: 3      val: 4
```

What was `mid` in the first level is now called `head` (I call it `head'` to distinguish it from the `head` in the first level)

```
         ListNode    ListNode
head' -> next     -> next     -> null
         val: 3      val: 4
```

`getMid(head)` again changes the list and returns a reference to the middle element:

```
         ListNode
head' -> next     -> null
         val: 3

         ListNode
mid'  -> next     -> null
         val: 4
```

Comment: im still confused because head wasnt modified before that call. mid points to the middle of the list but head wasnt changed when it gets to that call. right?